# Cool and Quiet! does not work under Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, 64-bit, amd-processor, governor

I've installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on an **Athlon 5050e** with an Asus M2N68-VM MB. Everything works fine and fast with my Avant SSD, but the **energy consumtion is about 60 -80 Watt**, which is quite a lot!

I've browsed the web and found out that AMD has a feature called '**Cool And Quiet**', so I activated it in the BIOS and reinstalled Ubuntu Server.

And: nothing changed! This is what I figured out:

I went to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq`
and printed cpuinfo_min, cpuinfo_max and governor.

- min speed is 1GHz
- max speed is 2,6GHz
- governor is set to 'ondemand'

Everything looks fine but 'time_in_state' shows that the CPU is running on max. speed - all the time.

Maybe you can help me, solve this problem. I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: To validate that the cpufreqency is realy that high: Could you install `cpufrequtils` and run `cpufreq-info`? Than you'll see the current frequency on all processors.

Comment: Of course: `current CPU frequency is 2600 MHz (asserted by call to hardware)`

Comment: What is the machine doing? Does this happen even when the server is idle? Have you checked `top` to see what is taking up the CPU?

Comment: The machine is doing nothing - in the moment. It is a fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 server. `htop` confirms that cpu-load is about 0,9% (which is used by htop).

Comment: And is the scaling_max_freq and scaling_min_freq configured correctly? Because the gouvernor may be set to on demand and the physical min speed be 1 GHz, but if the scaling is still at minimum 2,6 GHz, it will stay at 2,6 GHz. And are the other processors all at the same state? Could you maybe post the full output of cpufreq-info? (And: Does the same happen when you use the `powersave`-gouvernor?)

Comment: Thx @DavidGeorgReichelt @terdon that solved my problem.  The scaling_min_frequence was set to 2,6GHz. I reinstalled Ubuntu Server again and this problem still occours. I've changed the min/max speed in `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils`. This solved my problem, but I still don't know, why Ubuntu isn't able to set the right speed for this CPU. Thanks for all your comments!